# How to tell when JUnit finishes by just using a TestWatcher?

Tags: java, pdf, selenium, junit

I need to:

- watch the tests
- gather information
- build a report from the tests

The tests will be started via TeamCity. I create a TestWatcher object to listen for test results, and this TestWatcher is included in each JUnit class that contains tests. I had a listener which would listen to when the entire suite is completed, but I had to add that programmatically. Since I am now using TeamCity to run the tests and generate results, I believe I have lost that capability. I have been asked to also produce a PDF report with the TeamCity results. All I need to know is when the tests are finished so I can know when to start building my report. Is there anyway to accomplish this by just using a TestWatcher?

Below is what my TestWatcher looks like at the moment. BaseTestResult is just a class that contains results of the tests, and organizes them in order to print them out easier. I am also using Selenium, and the driver variable is of type WebDriver:

```
@Rule
public TestWatcher watchman = new TestWatcher() {
    private BaseTestResult currentTest;
    private long startTime;
    private long endTime;

    @Override
    protected void starting(Description d) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        currentTest = new BaseTestResult(d);
        currentTest.setBrowser(type);
        if (d.getAnnotation(TestDescription.class) != null) {
            currentTest.setDescription(d.getAnnotation(
                    TestDescription.class).description());
        }
        currentTest.setSuite(d.getTestClass().getName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded(Description d) {
        currentTest.setSucceeded(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description d) {
        currentTest.setThrowable(e);
    }

    @Override
    protected void finished(Description d) {
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        currentTest.setRuntime(endTime - startTime);
        String fileName = d.getMethodName() + type + ".png";
        File srcFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
                .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String filePath = "./screens/" + fileName;
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, new File(filePath));
            currentTest.setScreenshotPath(filePath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.severe(e.toString());
        }

        if (currentTest.getSucceeded()) {
            BaseListener.getSuiteResult().addPassed(currentTest);
        } else {
            BaseListener.getSuiteResult().addFailed(currentTest);
        }

        // Quit, the web driver
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
@ClassRule // the magic is done here
public static TestRule classWatchman = new TestWatcher() {
    @Override
    protected void starting(Description desc) {
        System.out.println(desc.testCount()); // insert actual logic here
    }
};
```

This watches whole class instead of every test. That means that it gives you the number of tests in a suite on the start of the suite. Then, every time you call `BaseListener.getSuiteResult().addPassed(currentTest);` or `BaseListener.getSuiteResult().addFailed(currentTest);` you can check whether you have already added the number of tests in a suite (meaning the suite is done).

Or, even better,

```
@ClassRule
public static TestRule classWatchman = new TestWatcher() {
    @Override
    protected void finished(Description desc) {
        System.out.println("Suite completed!"); // insert actual logic here
    }
};
```

If you have multiple classes containing tests, you can create a single AllMyTests class containing all of those! This AllMyTests class can be then run by JUnit. In this case, @ClassRule will behave as a @SuiteRule (which doesn't exist).

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ First.class, Second.class, Third.class })
public class AllMyTests {
    // nothing to do
}
```

Comment: btw I just realized that we both use our Test _Watcher_ named in the old way "Watchman" :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is definitely a step in the right direction. What if I have multiple classes? I am planning on having more than one test class, and would like to build a report from the results of all test classes that run.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
@ClassRule 
public Static TestWatcher watchman= new TestWatcher() {
  @Override
  protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {


  logger.info(description.getMethodName()+"Failed!"+" "+e.getMessage());
  }

  @Override
  protected void succeeded(Description description) {

    logger.info(description.getMethodName()+" " + "success!");
  }
  @Override
  protected void finished(Description desc) {
  logger.info("Suite completed!");
  }
};
```